# Laravel local: fopen Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel, fopen, permission-denied

I need help to fix this error:

> fopen(/Subckt.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied

- I'm using Laravel
- I working on the website locally by using the cmd with the php
  artisan serve command
- I've found some potential solution with chmod but since I'm using localhost I dont think it works
- The website is running a php code to do modification to a txt file. Then I saving it to another file. On the root folder.
- The whole website folder is stated as readonly, I can't modify that. (Im using windows 7, when I uncheck the box it gets always rechecked. But I managed to remove the read only from the text files(Subckt.txt and \npn.lib).
- I tried my code without laravel in a php and html file and it works.

Here is my partial code:

```php
// Load the output file
$outputFile = fopen("\Subckt.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!"); 

// Load the input file into string
$inputFile = "\npn.lib";

// Put the input file in a string variable
$inputFileContent = file_get_contents($inputFile);
```

Comment: Check your `base path`. The `fopen` function seems to be attempting to load the file from the root of the file system, which surely will have a permissions conflict.

Comment: In: $inputFile = "\npn.lib"; The \n is considered as a new line...

Comment: $inputFileContent = file_get_contents("C:\Users\username\Desktop\model\\testnpn.lib"); instead of 2 lines

Comment: I've transfered the txt and lib file to the Desktop. It now works

Answer (score -3, accepted):

By JasonLewis

Read up on [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/file_get_contents). The error is self explanatory. You passed a resource to file_get_contents(), not a string. You need to call it like:

```
    $contents = file_get_contents("textdoc.txt");
```

I found my answer there: https://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/117829-solved-file-get-contents-help/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have write permission on the file for the user running the php script? Who is the owner of the file you are trying to `fopen`? Maybe it's the www-data user trying to run the php script that is trying to open the file, but if the file is not owned by the www-data group or doesn't have global write permissions, it will conflict with php's permissions. If you are on linux, try using this `chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/the/project/folder`.  If the `chown` method doesn't work, then try using `chmod -R 775 /path/to/the/file`. On windows, I have no idea... I hope I could help some.